# Command to get first xx files in a directory listing

Tags: windows-7, windows

Given a directory, is there a way to just return the first, say, 100 files with their full path shown?

Comment: I'm *guessing* this has nothing to do with MS-DOS (which went out of fashion almost 20 years ago), but feel free to revert the retag (and remove the `windows-7` tag) if you really do need a MS-DOS solution... (hint: MS-DOS and the Windows (NT) command line are two very different things)

Comment: Correct, DOS solution not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
powershell ls "%cd%" -recurse ^| select -first 100 FullName
```

or

```
powershell ls "%cd%" -r^|select -f 100 FullName
```

without header:

```
powershell ls "%cd%" -r^|select -f 100 FullName^|ft -HideTableHeaders
```

or

```
powershell ls "%cd%" -r^|select -f 100 FullName^|ft -Hide
```

without directory:

```
powershell ls "%cd%" -r^|?{$_.Attributes -notmatch 'Directory'}^|select -f 100 FullName
```

only directory:

```
powershell ls "%cd%" -r^|?{$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'}^|select -f 100 FullName
```